# Deleting entries from tableview with keypress

Tags: cocoa, delegates, tableview, nstableview

I have a simple cocoa application with a table view displaying a few entries. I want the user to be able to delete any entry he wants by simply selecting it in the table and pressing "Delete". How do I detect the keypress of "Delete" and how do I know if it occurs when the user has selected an entry in the tableview?

**Edit: in case I've not made it clear, "Delete" refers to the backspace key on a mac keyboard and not a GUI button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to just assign a key equivalent (keyboard shortcut) to the Edit menu's "Delete" item and set its action to your controller's `delete:` method.

Answer (score 4):

Subclass the table view, and have it send its delegate events when delete is pressed.

**MyTableView.h:**

```
@interface MyTableView : NSTableView

@end

@protocol MyTableViewDelegate <NSTableViewDelegate>

-(BOOL)deleteKeyPressedForTableView:(MyTableView *)tableView;

@end
```

**MyTableView.m:**

```
+(unichar)firstCharPressedForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if (![[theEvent characters] length]) return -1;
    return [[theEvent characters] characterAtIndex:0];
}

+(BOOL)eventIsDeleteKeyPressed:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    switch ([MyTableView firstCharPressedForEvent:theEvent]) {
        case NSDeleteFunctionKey:
        case NSDeleteCharFunctionKey:
        case NSDeleteCharacter:
            return YES;
        default:
            return NO;
    }
}

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if ([MyTableView eventIsDeleteKeyPressed:theEvent])
        if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(deleteKeyPressedForTableView:)])
            if ([(id<MyTableViewDelegate>)[self delegate] deleteKeyPressedForTableView:self])
                return;

    // The delegate wasn't able to handle it
    [super keyDown:theEvent];
}
```

**Table view's delegate:**

```
- (BOOL)deleteKeyPressedForTableView:(MyTableView *)tableView {
    // check if row is selected
    if (no_row_selected) return NO;
    // handle deletion
    if (error_condition) return NO;    
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one table, a simpler solution is to implement a few `NSResponder` methods in your window controller or view controller:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [self interpretKeyEvents:@[event]];
}

- (void)deleteBackward:(id)sender
{
    // use the tableView's selectedRow to determine what/if to delete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift 4 version of the answer that @paulmelnikow gave.

```swift
protocol MyTableViewDelegate: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func deleteKeyPressed(for tableView: MyTableView)
}

class MyTableView: NSTableView {
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        guard let myDelegate = delegate as? MyTableViewDelegate, deletePressed(event: event) else {
            super.keyDown(with: event)
            return
        }

        myDelegate.deleteKeyPressed(for: self)
    }

    fileprivate func deletePressed(event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        guard let firstChar = event.characters?.first, let uniScalar = firstChar.unicodeScalars.first else {
            return false
        }

        let char = Int(uniScalar.value)

        switch char {
        case NSDeleteFunctionKey, NSDeleteCharFunctionKey, NSDeleteCharacter:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```